# Retrieve model matrix from regression output

Tags: r, regression

I would like to retrieve the cleaned input covariates and outcome variable after running several regression models from the model output - I would like access the data as it is used in the actual estimation.
For lm() and lfe's felm() function, one can access both outcome variable and covariates with specific "model" ouputs:

```
library(estimatr)
library(lfe)

set.seed(1)
N <- 100
X <- abs(rnorm(N))
y <- 1 + 2*X + rnorm(N)
data <- data.frame(y = y, X = X)
data[1, ] <- NA
head(data)
#         y         X
#1       NA        NA
#2 1.409403 0.1836433
#3 1.760336 0.8356286
#4 4.348590 1.5952808
#5 1.004431 0.3295078
#6 4.408224 0.8204684

lm_fit <- lm(y ~ log(X), data = data)
lm_robust_fit <- lm_robust(y ~ log(X), data = data)
felm_fit <- felm(y ~ log(X), data = data)

head(lm_fit$model)
#         y     log(X)
#2 1.409403 -1.6947599
#3 1.760336 -0.1795710
#4 4.348590  0.4670498
#5 1.004431 -1.1101553
#6 4.408224 -0.1978799
#7 2.691566 -0.7186105

head(eval(felm_fit$model))
#         y     log(X)
#2 1.409403 -1.6947599
#3 1.760336 -0.1795710
#4 4.348590  0.4670498
#5 1.004431 -1.1101553
#6 4.408224 -0.1978799
#7 2.691566 -0.7186105
```

The lm_robust function from the estimatr package does not have a "model"-object as an output. One way to obtain the model input would be to use the expand.model.frame function:

```
tmp <- expand.model.frame(lm_robust_fit, 
                  extras = ~ 1, 
                  na.expand = TRUE, 
                  envir = globalenv())
head(tmp)
#         y     log(X)
#2 1.409403 -1.6947599
#3 1.760336 -0.1795710
#4 4.348590  0.4670498
#5 1.004431 -1.1101553
#6 4.408224 -0.1978799
#7 2.691566 -0.7186105
```

Now, is there another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Have you checked the function `model.matrix()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `unclass` the object `lm_robust_fit` you will see that it simply doesn't store the values from its model frame, so you can't extract them directly from the object.

However, `felm_fit` doesn't contain them either - as you show it instead provides the call to `model.frame` needed to produce it, which you just need to `eval`.

If you look at the code for `lm`, it actually produces its `model` data in exactly the same way, except it takes the extra step of running `eval` on the `model.frame` call.

You can do exactly as `lm` and `felm_fit` does, by calling `model.frame` directly, which by default uses the `data` argument that was passed to the original call, and evaluates it in the correct environment. This is similar to, but safer than, the solution you came up with, because you do not have to specify where the data is coming from (i.e. you don't need to worry about the object being inside a scope other than `globalenv`).

Calling `model.frame` directly will also work for all three different types of model, so it would probably simplify your code to use this single function to retrieve any model frame regardless of the type.

So you can do:

```
head(model.frame(lm_fit))
#>          y     log(X)
#> 2 1.409403 -1.6947599
#> 3 1.760336 -0.1795710
#> 4 4.348590  0.4670498
#> 5 1.004431 -1.1101553
#> 6 4.408224 -0.1978799
#> 7 2.691566 -0.7186105

head(model.frame(felm_fit))
#>          y     log(X)
#> 2 1.409403 -1.6947599
#> 3 1.760336 -0.1795710
#> 4 4.348590  0.4670498
#> 5 1.004431 -1.1101553
#> 6 4.408224 -0.1978799
#> 7 2.691566 -0.7186105

head(model.frame(lm_robust_fit))
#>          y     log(X)
#> 2 1.409403 -1.6947599
#> 3 1.760336 -0.1795710
#> 4 4.348590  0.4670498
#> 5 1.004431 -1.1101553
#> 6 4.408224 -0.1978799
#> 7 2.691566 -0.7186105
```